# How to test if a condition does not contradict other conditions

Tags: algorithm

I'm on Angular (typescript) but it's more a question of pure algorithm

I have an array that receives conditions (as a string).
example: ['a<b', 'a==b-1',...]

the array receives a new condition: if the new condition doesn't contradict those already contained in the array

so that:

```
array = []

a==b   -> yes  ['a==b']
c<b    -> yes  ['a==b', 'c<b']
c==a   -> no   ['a==b', 'c<b'] impossible because a==b and c<b
c==a-1 -> yes  ['a==b', 'c<b', 'c==a-1']
...
```

I limit myself to the conditions of equality, superiority, inferiority (strict): ==, >, < to begin and i'll add <=, >= if it's not really more complicated...

I want to do that with just real number but the condition can be like:
'a+2<b+c+n+t', 'a=c+2', 'a=b', 'a=1', 'a<4'...

Actually, I'm still at the guesswork stage without succeeding in finding an obvious angle of resolution.

- replace the variables with integers to test the conditions between them ?

I cannot find anything convincing... right now!
I do not realize the level of difficulty of such an algorithm, does this seem simple to you on first reading?

Do you have any solutions, leads?

Comment: What have **YOU** tried / researched so far? Share **YOUR** findings / ideas / code.

Comment: You might get more useful answers if you could be more explicit about what your conditions are. For example are the always of the form lhs cmp rhs where cmp is one of < <= etc? What form can the left and right hand sides take? What do the veriables represent: integers, real numbers, ...

Answer (score 2):

hat you want is to know if the constraint-satisfaction-problem (CSP) has at least one solution.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem

There are a vast amount of papers, algorithms and tool out there to solve this.

Comment: Very interesting, thanx, I will come back when I have more information on what I want